# Bluetooth devices are disconnected just after connected in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, connection

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8852be
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b760 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP
```